# Post Array into array array in php

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

I want to put my post array into array array. I have the following form (this form is inside a foreach loop) which will post array data like the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cl[]" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="cd[]" value="">
```

and the post array contains when viewed in firebug:

```
cl[]    4
cl[]    4
cd[]    John
cd[]    Shaw
```

and I want these value in one single like below:

```
$allData = array(
    array(
        'cl' => 4,
        'cd' => 'John',
    ),
    array(
        'cl' => 4,
        'cd' => 'Shaw',
    )
);
```

Please help.

Comment: how are these input elements rendered? are they dynamic? (add new row button) or this structure is static? (html form is hardcoded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For easy access name the array (optional)

```
<input type="text" name="data[cl][]" />
<input type="text" name="data[cd][]" />
<input type="text" name="data[cl][]" />
<input type="text" name="data[cd][]" />
```

Loop with a double foreach:

```
foreach($_POST['data'] as $key => $row) {
        foreach($row as $subkey => $values) {
                $array[$subkey][$key]   =   $values;
            }
    }

 print_r($array); ?>
```

Gives you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cl] => val1
            [cd] => val2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cl] => val3
            [cd] => val4
        )

)
```

Comment: You really save my day. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cl[] =   4;
$cl[]  =  4;
$cd[]   = 'John';
$cd[]    ='Shaw';
if (!empty($cl) && !empty($cd)) {
    $count = count($cl);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $newArr[] = array('c1' => $cl[$i], 'cd' => $cd[$i]);
    }
}
print_r($newArr);
```

Comment: for loop is faster than foreach which I have already used. I don't thing any modification is there to speed up.